# Are there any clojure libraries that provide the reloads the entire project

Tags: clojure

There is a great function in `immutant.dev` - `reload-project!` that takes your project.clj, looks at the changes, downloads the dependencies and loads the missing classes in your namespace http://immutant.org/documentation/current/interactive.html

Are there any libs that mimic this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for but Stuart Sierra's [tools.namespace](https://github.com/clojure/tools.namespace) project might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Emacs the [ritz](https://github.com/pallet/ritz) project has a similar command: [`nrepl-ritz-reload-project`](https://github.com/pallet/ritz/blob/9f9d2e724083e084bb723acad272c86f68b49add/nrepl/README.md#nrepl-ritz-emacs-commands). Take a look at [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=sA5zOLCa3Xw#t=2174s) presentation to see it in action (the link goes directly to the `nrepl-ritz-reload-project` part).